DEAP eaSimple in python crashes becouse of too many laggs
Error
I get SyntaxError: too many nested parentheses.
File /home/tilen/genetic_programming/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3577 in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  Cell In[4],   line 80
    pop, log = eaSimple(pop, toolbox, 0.5, 0.2, 100000, stats=stats, halloffame=hof, verbose=True)

  File /home/tilen/genetic_programming/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deap/algorithms.py:173 in eaSimple
    for ind, fit in zip(invalid_ind, fitnesses):

  Cell In[4],   line 52
    func = toolbox.compile(expr=individual)

File /home/tilen/genetic_programming/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deap/gp.py:494 in compile
    return eval(code, pset.context, {})

  File <string>:1
    lambda Lag1,Lag2,Lag3: multiply(protectedSqrt(multiply(Lag3, Lag2)), sin(sin(subtract(subtract(subtract(sin(subtract(multiply(sin(sin( 

Code:
## Preprocessing:
def preprocessing(df):
    df['Return'] = df['close'].pct_change().fillna(0)
    df['Lag1'] = df['Return'].shift(1).fillna(0)
    df['Lag2'] = df['Return'].shift(2).fillna(0)
    df['Lag3'] = df['Return'].shift(3).fillna(0)

    df['Target'] = df['Return'].shift(-1).fillna(0)
    
    X = df[features]
    y = df['Target']
    
    return df, X, y

features = ['Lag1', 'Lag2', 'Lag3']
btc_data, X, y = preprocessing(df)

#print(btc_data)
print(X)
print(y)

## gp
def protectedDiv(left, right):
    if right == 0:
        return 1
    try:
        return np.divide(left, right + 2.226e-308)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 1
    
def protectedLog(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 1
    return np.log(x)

def protectedSqrt(x):
    if x < 0:
        return 0
    return np.sqrt(x)

def protectedExp(x):
    if x > np.log(np.finfo(np.float32).max):
        return np.finfo(np.float32).max
    return np.exp(x)

gp.staticLimit(operator.attrgetter('height'), 50)
pset = gp.PrimitiveSet("MAIN", len(features))
pset.addPrimitive(np.add, 2)
pset.addPrimitive(np.subtract, 2)
pset.addPrimitive(np.multiply, 2)
pset.addPrimitive(protectedDiv, 2)
pset.addPrimitive(np.sin, 1) 
pset.addPrimitive(np.cos, 1)  
#pset.addPrimitive(np.tan, 1)
pset.addPrimitive(np.negative, 1)
pset.addPrimitive(protectedLog, 1)
pset.addPrimitive(protectedExp, 1)
pset.addPrimitive(protectedSqrt, 1)

pset.addEphemeralConstant("rand101", partial(random.uniform, -1, 1))
pset.renameArguments(ARG0='Lag1', ARG1='Lag2', ARG2='Lag3')

if 'FitnessMin' in creator.__dict__:
    del creator.FitnessMin
if 'Individual' in creator.__dict__:
    del creator.Individual
creator.create("FitnessMin", base.Fitness, weights=(-1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", gp.PrimitiveTree, fitness=creator.FitnessMin)

def evalSymbReg(individual, X, y):
    func = toolbox.compile(expr=individual)
    predictions = np.array([func(*x) for x in X], dtype=np.float128)
    return mean_squared_error(y, predictions),

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("expr", gp.genHalfAndHalf, pset=pset, min_=1, max_=2)
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initIterate, creator.Individual, toolbox.expr)
toolbox.register("compile", gp.compile, pset=pset)
toolbox.register("evaluate", evalSymbReg, X=X.values, y=y.values)
toolbox.register("select", tools.selTournament, tournsize=3)
toolbox.register("mate", gp.cxOnePoint)
toolbox.register("mutate", gp.mutUniform, expr=toolbox.expr, pset=pset)
toolbox.register("expr_mut", gp.genFull, min_=0, max_=2)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

toolbox.register("map", map)

pop = toolbox.population(n=100)
hof = tools.HallOfFame(1)
stats = tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
stats.register("avg", np.mean)
stats.register("std", np.std)
stats.register("min", np.min)
stats.register("max", np.max)

pop, log = eaSimple(pop, toolbox, 0.5, 0.2, 100, stats=stats, halloffame=hof, verbose=True)

print(hof[0])

I think I limited gp with static limit: gp.staticLimit(operator.attrgetter('height'), 50). I think something over 90 is the limit.

The maximum number of nested parentheses in CPython is 200 since version 3.8.
There's no way to change that limit unless you recompile Python – you will need to figure out how to make that library not generate code that uses more than 200 nested parentheses.

Thank you for fast answear. I can't find setting for limit of nested parentheses in  documentation
